Prove that $I_{\mathbb{Q}}$ doesn't have a limit at $x=1$
Prove that $I_{\mathbb{Q}}$ doesn't have a limit at $x=1$
$I_{\mathbb{Q}}= \begin{cases} 1 &\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0 &\forall x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$
I'll preface this by saying that I know no RA whatsoever and nothing do do with. sequences, series or anything of that sort beyond basic APs, GPS and HPs.
So to start I approach it from a rational number.
So
$|x-1|<\delta \to 0 \leq \varepsilon$
I'm not sure what to make of this
Now I approach it from an irrational number so
$|x-1|<\delta $ so $(1- \delta <x<\delta+1) \implies  1<\varepsilon$, which works as there is some $x$ which is irrational between any two reals.
Thus the limit is $0$ for irrationals which makes sense. Not sure of what to do with the case for rationals though

Start with $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit
$$(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x\in\mathbb R)\quad 0<|x-1|<\delta \implies |I_{\mathbb Q}(x)-L|<\varepsilon. \tag{1}$$
To prove that the limit doesn't exist we need to prove that
$$(\exists\varepsilon > 0)(\forall \delta > 0)(\exists x\in\mathbb R)\quad 0<|x-1|<\delta \text{ and } |I_{\mathbb Q}(x)-L|\geq\varepsilon. \tag{2}$$
So, take some fixed $\varepsilon$, which we will specify later. For any $\delta>0$ we can find rational $x_r$ and irrational $x_i$ in $(1-\delta,1)\cup(1,1+\delta)$, so $|I_{\mathbb Q}(x)-L|$ can take both $|1-L|$ and $|-L|$ for its values. At least one of them needs to be greater or equal to $\varepsilon$ so that we can prove that $L$ is not the limit according to $(2)$. To achieve that we can take $\varepsilon = \frac{|1-L|}{2}$ or $\varepsilon = \frac{|-L|}{2}$, as long as they are not $0$ (remember that $\varepsilon$ needs to be strictly positive) and they can't both be $0$ at the same time. Formally, we can write
$$\varepsilon = \max\left\{\frac{|1-L|}2,\frac{|-L|}2\right\}.$$
Now, to wrap everything, if $\frac{|1-L|}2 \geq \frac{|-L|}2$, then $\varepsilon = \frac{|1-L|}2>0$ and for any $\delta>0$ take rational $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta$. We then have $|I_{\mathbb Q}(x)-L| = |1-L|\geq \frac{|1-L|}2=\varepsilon.$
If $\frac{|1-L|}2 \leq \frac{|-L|}2$, then $\varepsilon = \frac{|-L|}2>0$ and for any $\delta>0$ take irrational $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta$. We then have $|I_{\mathbb Q}(x)-L| = |-L|\geq \frac{|-L|}2=\varepsilon.$
This proves that no real $L$ can be the limit, according to $(2)$, so the limit doesn't exist.

Let me remind you the definition of continuity:

A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be continuous at $a\in \mathbb R$ if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)_n \subset \mathbb R$ converging to $a$, the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(a)$.

Therefore, negating this definition, one gets that:

A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be discontinuous at $a\in \mathbb R$ if and only if there exists $(x_n)_n \subset \mathbb R$ converging to $a$ and $(f(x_n))_n$ doesn't converge to $f(a)$.

Now consider two sequences $(x_n)_n \subset \mathbb Q$ and $ (y_n)_n \subset \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$ such that
$$x_n \to 1 \quad \text{and} \quad y_n \to 1.$$
Note that this is possible as both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$ are dense in $\mathbb R$.
What can you conclude for the sequences
$$(I_{\mathbb Q}(x_n))_n\quad \text{and} \quad (I_{\mathbb Q}(y_n))_n~?$$

I unfortunately do not know sequences, and neither do I really know how to prove density of the rationals and irrationals, just thought this would be a good way to ensure I understand epsilon-delta limits. Is there any other way?

The question doesn't ask about continuity, it asks that you prove that $\not\exists\lim_{x\to 1}I_{\mathbb Q}(x)$.

This is the definition of sequential continuity, not the definition of continuity, the latter involving $\epsilon-\delta$. The equivalence of these two notions, even for $\mathbb{R}$, is non-trivial and requires some weaker form of the Axiom of Choice.

@Jianing Song I considered $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. The equivalence of the two definitions of continuity in this context is quite standard and is proved in most 1st year text book.
